# Custom NavigationView gets messed up when importing the presentationMode Environment variable

Tags: swiftui

I'm using a custom navigation bar view & setup, where I hide it in the main view and show it in the child. All works fine, until I added this line in the child:

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
```

I needed it in the child so we can pop back to the main view. Now when I open the child then click on back (not even using the env variable) then open the child view again the navigation bar is not ignoring the safe areas as it was before. Here's a gif of the issue:

[image]

See the new grey space in the child view?

This is the code for this:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct NavBarApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                MainView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    init() {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .clear
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
        UINavigationBar.appearance().prefersLargeTitles = false
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            NavigationLink("Go to child view", destination: ChildView())
            Spacer()
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .tabItem {
            Text("Home")
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 66)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Spacer()
            Text("Chlid View")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
            Spacer()
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .navigationBarTitle("View A", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: AnyView(Button(action: {
        }) {
            Text("Add")
        }))
    }
}
```

What I noticed:

1. Removing the presentationMode fixes the issue.
2. Not adding a button on the navigation bar in the child view fixes the issue.
3. Not customising the NavigationBar's appearance in MainView also fixes the issue.

Any ideas on what's going on and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I narrowed it down to this line in the appearance setup:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Removing it solved the issue. Removing it hasn't affected the look of the custom navigation bar so I'll go with this solution for now.